# JavaScript Noise Function Problems

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, noise

I've been trying to learn about generating noise and find that I understand most of it but I'm having a bit of trouble with a script.

I used [this page](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htm) as a guide to write [this script in JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/L2VsP/2/) with the ultimate purpose of creating some noise on canvas.

It's definitely creating something but it's tucked all the way over on the left. Also, refreshing the page seems to create the same pattern over and over again.

1. What have I done wrong that the "noisy" part of the image is smushed on the left? How can I make it look more like the cloudy perlin noise?
2. I don't really understand why it doesn't produce a new pattern each time. What would I need to change in order to receive a random pattern each time the script is run?

Thank you for your help!

```
/* NOISE—Tie it all together
*/
function perlin2d(x,y){
    var total = 0;

    var p = persistence;
    var n = octaves - 1;

    for(var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        var frequency = Math.pow(2, i);
        var amplitude = Math.pow(p, i);

        total = total + interpolatenoise(x * frequency, y * frequency) * amplitude;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: I don't see where in your code you are varying the inputs to the algorithm, such as with random numbers.  Your algorithms are deterministic - which is to say that they will always give consistent results given identical inputs.  Not sure about the "smushy" part of your noise though.

Comment: agree with Matt.  Where is persistence defined, and octaves.  If it is always the same, then it will always return the same result.

Answer (score 5):

I've forked your fiddle and fixed a couple things to make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/KkDVr/2/

The main problem was the flawed pseudorandom generator "noise", that always returned 1 for large enough values of x and y. I've replaced it with a random values table that is queried with integer coordinates:

```js
var values = [];
for(var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    values[i] = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        values[i][j] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
    }
}
function noise(x, y) {
    x = parseInt(Math.min(width - 1, Math.max(0, x)));
    y = parseInt(Math.min(height - 1, Math.max(0, y)));
    return values[x][y];
}
```

However, the implementation provided in the tutorial you followed uses simplified algorithms that are really poorly optimized. I suggest you the excellent real-world noise tutorial at http://scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-advanced-lessons/noise-part-1.

Finally, maybe you could be interested in a project of mine: http://lencinhaus.github.com/canvas-noise.
It's a javascript app that renders perlin noise on an html5 canvas and allows to tweak almost any parameter visually. I've ported the original noise algorithm implementation by Ken Perlin to javascript, so that may be useful for you. You can find the source code here: https://github.com/lencinhaus/canvas-noise/tree/gh-pages.

Hope that helps, bye!